# Pycharm type hint warning on opening Path object

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

Using the following code:

```py
from pathlib import Path

file = Path("test.txt")

with open(file) as fl:
    pass
```

Pycharm gives the following warning on `file`

```
Unexpected type(s): (Path) 

Possible types: 
  (Union[str, bytes, int]) 
  (Union[str, bytes, int, PathLike]) less... (Ctrl+F1) 

Inspection info: This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations.
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: It is a known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30747

Comment: workaround: use type hinting to label paths as "Union[pathlib.Path, os.PathLike]"

Comment: To compound @MarkTeese answer.  You can define a custom typehint like so: `PathLike = Union[pathlib.Path, os.PathLike]`

Comment: This has been fixed in the [latest 2020.2 EAP](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30747#focus=Comments-27-4254660.0-0)

Answer (score -3):

You can use it like this

```
    file = "test.txt"

    with open(file) as fl:
        pass
```

- Pycharm even gives you prompts to possible files that you might want to use. I use it like this with no problems.
- If the file you are looking for isn't in the same directory as the code you need to add full path

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question at all, which is about `Path` objects.